# Starting point of deriving a FOL proof tree

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

For a question statement given in the book "[A Concise Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.lk/books?id=Ikp2dGWT5O4C)" by Patrick J. Hurley, I want to derive the FOL resolution proof tree using the method of contradiction.

The Question statement is

> If all the physicians are either hematologists or neurologists, then
>   there are no cardiologists. But Dr. Frank is a cardiologist.
>   Therefore, some physicians are not neurologists. (P, H, N, C)

Using the predicate interpretations of the above statements given in this [website](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/a-concise-introduction-to-logic-12th-edition-chapter-8.3ii-solutions-9781285965567), I have converted them to Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) clauses as follows to build up the proof tree.

all the physicians are either hematologists or neurologists, then there are no cardiologists.

> 1 : P(A) ∨ ￢C(z)
>   2 : ￢H(A) ∨ C(z)
>   3 : ￢N(A) ∨ C(z)

Dr. Frank is a cardiologist

> 4 : C(Frank)

Negation of Conclusion "some physicians are not neurologists"

> 5: ￢P(x) ∨ N(x)

**My issue is,** from which two statements should we 1st use to draw the proof tree? Statement 1 with 5, or 3 with 5, or 4 with 1 or ....? Do we need to consider the order of the statements in the KB?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun Edited the question. Hope it's now highlighted the problem I'm having :)

Comment: But what method do you want to use ? [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, Resolution but with proof of contradiction. To buildup a proof tree like [criminal west problem](https://books.google.lk/books?id=4fyShrIFXg4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA326#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I do not know what is "criminal west problem"... and yes, Resoution uses the premises and the negation of the conclusion, But proof tree is the answer below, that seems you do not like...

Comment: In any case, subst F for z in 1), 2) and 3) and apply resolution rule to get : 6) P(A), 7) ￢H(A) and 8) ￢N(A). Then subst A for x in 5) and apply resolution rule with 6) and 8) to derive the empty clause.

Answer (score 1):

> If all the physicians are either hematologists or neurologists, then there are no cardiologists.

This can be written as $\forall p (Hp\lor Np)\to (\lnot\exists q Cq)$

> But Dr. Frank is a cardiologist.

This can be written as $Cf$.

> Therefore, some physicians are not neurologists.

This can be written as $\exists r \lnot Nr$.

---

This is assuming cardiologists are physicians.

To prove the last statement from the other two, compute the tableau of $$\lnot((\forall p (Hp\lor Np)\to (\lnot\exists q Cq))\land Cf)\to (\exists r \lnot Nr)$$ and show that it is closed.

You should get something like this:

[image]

Each path ends in a contradiction, hence the result.

Comment: I'm bit puzzled. Don't we need to convert them into CNF? I'm trying to buildup a proof tree like [criminal west problem](https://books.google.lk/books?id=4fyShrIFXg4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA326#v=onepage&q&f=false)